# Change nested component in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios, mobile-application

I am using the code below, My data list is inside the    . Right now as per below code  Icon is not working inside . Via some clicks Toggle for `this.state.rmvCircle` is happening. Boolean is changing but  Icon is not getting toggle.

But If I wrote  just inside the  So  Icon is working fine as per the toggle change via some function.

What extra thing I need to implement for refreshing  Icon inside the listItem.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Container,
  Header,
  Title,
  Content,
  Button,
  Icon,
  List,
  ListItem,
  Text,
  Left,
  Right,
  Body,
  View,
  Spinner,
} from "native-base";
import {AsyncStorage, 
  RefreshControl,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Alert
} from "react-native";
import Display from 'react-native-display';
import {fetchApi} from '../../includes/function';
import {networkFailure} from '../../includes/function';
import styles from "./styles";
const GLOBAL = require('../../includes/Global');

class notifylog extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     jsonData : '',
     isLoading : true,
     rmvCircle : false
    };
  }

  notifylogFun(){
    let userId = this.state.user;
    if(userId == null || userId==undefined){
      alert("User not found");
      return false;
    }
    const json = JSON.stringify({"userId":userId});
    return fetch(GLOBAL.BASE_URL+'services.php?action=notifylogFun',{
      method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Accept: 'application/json'
        },
        body: json
      })
    .then(function(response) {
      if (!response.ok) {
        this.setState({isLoading: false,resultSet : false});
        throw Error(response.statusText);
      }
      return response;
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      if(responseJson.data.message == 'getData'){
        this.setState({isLoading: false, jsonData: responseJson.data.data, resultSet : true});
        return responseJson.data.data;
      }else if(responseJson.data.message == 'noData'){
        this.setState({isLoading: false, jsonData: responseJson.data.data, resultSet : false});
      }else{
        networkFailure("Network Failure.");
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      networkFailure("Network Failure");
    });
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('userId', (err, result) => {
      this.setState({
        user: result
      },this.notifylogFun);
    });
  }

  toggleDisplay() {
    let toggle = !this.state.rmvCircle;
    this.setState({rmvCircle: toggle});
  }

  render() {
    if(this.state.isLoading == true ) {
      return (
        <Container style={styles.container}>
          <Header
            style={{ backgroundColor : GLOBAL.ThemeHeader}}
            androidStatusBarColor="#dc2015"
            iosBarStyle="light-content"
          >
            <Left>
              <Button transparent onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}>
                <Icon style={{ color : GLOBAL.ThemeMenu}} name="arrow-back" />
              </Button>
            </Left>
            <Body>
              <Title style={{ color : GLOBAL.ThemeHeaderTitleColor}}>Notifications</Title>
            </Body>
            <Right />
          </Header>
            <View style={styles.loaderContainer}>
              <Spinner color="blue"/>
            </View>
        </Container>
      );
    } 
   else if(this.state.isLoading == false && this.state.resultSet == false) {
      return (
        <Container style={styles.container}>
          <Header
              style={{ backgroundColor : GLOBAL.ThemeHeader}}
              androidStatusBarColor="#dc2015"
              iosBarStyle="light-content"
            >
            <Left>
              <Button transparent onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}>
                <Icon style={{ color : GLOBAL.ThemeMenu}} name="arrow-back" />
              </Button>
            </Left>
            <Body>
              <Title style={{ color : GLOBAL.ThemeHeaderTitleColor}}>Notifications</Title>
            </Body>
            <Right />
          </Header>
          <View style={styles.loaderContainer}>
            <Text>No Notifications Logs</Text>
          </View>
        </Container>
      );
    } 
    else
    {
      return (
        <Container style={styles.container}>
          <Header style={{ backgroundColor : GLOBAL.ThemeHeader}} androidStatusBarColor="#dc2015" iosBarStyle="light-content">
            <Left>
              <Button transparent onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}>
                <Icon style={{ color : GLOBAL.ThemeMenu}} name="arrow-back" />
              </Button>
            </Left>
            <Body>
              <Title style={{ color : GLOBAL.ThemeHeaderTitleColor}}>Notifications</Title>
            </Body>
            <Right>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.toggleDisplay()}>
                <Text style={{ color : GLOBAL.ThemeMenu}}>
                  Clear
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </Right>
          </Header>
          <Content>
            <List 
              dataArray={this.state.jsonData}
              renderRow={data =>
              <ListItem style={{borderBottomWidth: 1,marginLeft: 0, backgroundColor : data.rowBg}}>

                <Left>
                  <Text>
                    {data.text}
                  </Text>
                </Left>
                <Right>
                   <Display 
                    enable={this.state.rmvCircle} 
                    enterDuration={500} 
                    exitDuration={250}
                    exit="fadeOutLeft"
                    enter="fadeInLeft"
                  >
                    <Icon style={{color:'red'}} name="md-remove-circle" />
                  </Display>
                </Right>
              </ListItem>}
            />
          </Content>
        </Container>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default notifylog;
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to toggle the Icon on-off depending on this.state.rmvCircle ?

```
{ this.state.rmvCircle && <Icon style={{color:'red'}} name="remove-circle" /> }
```

Comment: Yes, still same. your answer is working directly inside the content, But not inside ListItem Right, As per my question code

Comment: Are there any solution for this ?

Comment: I think i will need more code to understand your problem correctly... any chance you can share a codesandbox?

Comment: Hey Jayffe, Thanks for respond.
 I have edited my question with complete code please check. In the code sample if I write <Display> just after the <Content> It will work.
My scope is to clear notificationLog just like IPhone call logs. If clear button clicked then all rows should show any delete icon to delete only selected listitem.

Comment: hmmm... maybe the problem comes from how the `react-native-display` lib works, did you try to wrap `Icon` in a simple view `<View><Icon/></View>`  to check?

Comment: Yes, I tried condition render and { this.state.rmvCircle && <Icon style={{color:'red'}} name="remove-circle" /> } as well.. I am Having a doubt that child inside  is not refreshing  in react-native

Comment: OK, last chance :) did you try by removing the `Display` block just to check like this `<Right>{ this.state.rmvCircle && <Icon style={{color:'red'}} name="remove-circle" /> }</Right>`

Comment: I want to implement same delete function like https://support.apple.com/en-bn/HT207729
can you please suggest other option to do the same

Answer (score 0):

List content is rendered if we make our list by using dataSource :)